# Facebook style hide|Delete

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, facebook

Can any one suggest any way to do facebook style, news feed hide, delete, without updating the page, or redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery and use the $.hide(); method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like jQuery UI stuff? 
Have a look at the demos. It hooks nicely into AJAX calls
http://jqueryui.com/demos/